# Django ChoiceField Initial Value Not Setting for All ChoiceFields

Tags: django, django-models, choicefield, formfield

I have this really weird issue goin on and haven't been able to figure it out. I have a form with ChoiceFields, I load data from a model object and set that as the inital value for the form. Only half of the fields actually get set to the inital value that the object specified.

Heres The Form

```
sku = forms.CharField(max_length=200, required=True)
weight = forms.DecimalField(min_value=.1, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, required=True, help_text="Enter Weight In Pounds")
mail_class = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MAIL_CLASS, required=True)
package_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PACKAGE_TYPE, required=True)
shipping_rule = forms.IntegerField(min_value=1, required=False)
new_weight = forms.DecimalField(min_value=.1, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, required=False, help_text="Enter Weight for new shipping method In Pounds")
new_mail_class = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MAIL_CLASS, required=False, initial='None')
new_package_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PACKAGE_TYPE, required=False, initial='None')
max_shipping_rule = forms.IntegerField(min_value=2, required=False)
max_weight = forms.DecimalField(min_value=.1, max_digits=4, decimal_places=1, required=False, help_text="Enter Weight for new shipping method In Pounds")
max_mail_class = forms.ChoiceField(choices=MAIL_CLASS, required=False, initial='None')
max_package_type = forms.ChoiceField(choices=PACKAGE_TYPE, required=False, initial='None')
```

And heres were I set it in the view

```
data = {
        'sku': shipping_info.sku,
        'weight': shipping_info.weight,
        'mail_class': shipping_info.mailclass,
        'package_type': shipping_info.packagetype,
        'shipping_rule': shipping_info.shippingrule,
        'new_weight': shipping_info.newweight,
        'new_mail_class': shipping_info.newmailclass,
        'new_package_type': shipping_info.newpackagetype,
        'max_shipping_rule': shipping_info.maxshippingrule,
        'max_weight': shipping_info.newmaxweight,
        'max_mail_class': shipping_info.maxmailclass,
        'max_package_type': shipping_info.maxpackagetype
    }

    form = ShippingType(initial=data)
```

Only the problem is the mail_class choicefields will be set to the right value in the template. The package_type are all just set on the first option though.

I have checked the values getting put in as inital and it all matches up to choices...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Found out what the problem was and its in the database itself.

There is some empty characters at the end of all the package types.

Now onto that mystery.